# php mysql query dynamic Group by value

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a mysql query that I want to get results by different order by values.

here is the code.

```
$strQuery =
"SELECT
    category.short_description AS category,
    asset.asset_code AS code,
    asset_model_number.short_description AS model,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_1 AS mnfserial,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_6 AS proctype,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_7 AS hdd,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_8 AS type,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_9 AS cond,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_10 AS drive,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_12 AS os,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_13 AS cpu,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_14 AS ram,
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
    asset_transaction
LEFT JOIN asset 
  ON asset_transaction.asset_id = asset.asset_id
LEFT JOIN asset_model 
  ON asset.asset_model_id = asset_model.asset_model_id
LEFT JOIN asset_model_number 
  ON asset.asset_model_number_id = asset_model_number.asset_model_number_id
LEFT JOIN asset_custom_field_helper 
  ON asset.asset_id = asset_custom_field_helper.asset_id
LEFT JOIN user_account 
  ON asset.created_by = user_account.user_account_id
LEFT JOIN category 
  ON asset_model.category_id = category.category_id
WHERE asset_transaction.transaction_id = ($txnid)
GROUP BY model";

$objDatabase = QApplication::$Database[1];

// Perform the Query
$objDbResult = $objDatabase->Query($strQuery);
```

This section I want to get results group by model

```
echo "<h3>Total Model No<br></h3><strong>";
while ($mixRow = $objDbResult->FetchArray()) {
echo $mixRow['model']. " = " .$mixRow['total'];
echo "<br><strong>";
}
```

Below section I want the results group by type

```
echo "<h3>Total Products<br></h3><strong>";
echo "<br>";
while ($row = $objDbResult->FetchArray()) {
echo $row['type']. " = " .$row['total'];
echo "<br><strong>";
```

I want to avoid writing the sql query each time, instead want to use this query and define my order by value somewhere. How can I do this?

Comment: you can simply have the query wherever you'd like and append the order by value... or have a function which you pass in the order by variable and that function creates the query for you (very easy to do) and simply returns you the string...

Comment: Can you show me an example please ?

Comment: I will favorite the question. I get home in about 5 hours. If your question is not answered yet, then I will provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider making a query builder class, so you can create queries more freely.

Anyhow, to just set the group by, you can create the function `getQueryGroupBy($query,$type)` as following:

```
function getQueryGroupBy($query, $type) {
    return $query . 'GROUP BY ' . $type;
}
```

Your query would be:

```
$strQuery = "SELECT
    category.short_description AS category,
    asset.asset_code AS code,
    asset_model_number.short_description AS model,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_1 AS mnfserial,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_6 AS proctype,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_7 AS hdd,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_8 AS type,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_9 AS cond,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_10 AS drive,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_12 AS os,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_13 AS cpu,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_14 AS ram,
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
    asset_transaction
    LEFT JOIN asset 
      ON asset_transaction.asset_id = asset.asset_id
    LEFT JOIN asset_model 
      ON asset.asset_model_id = asset_model.asset_model_id
    LEFT JOIN asset_model_number 
      ON asset.asset_model_number_id = asset_model_number.asset_model_number_id
    LEFT JOIN asset_custom_field_helper 
      ON asset.asset_id = asset_custom_field_helper.asset_id
    LEFT JOIN user_account 
      ON asset.created_by = user_account.user_account_id
    LEFT JOIN category 
      ON asset_model.category_id = category.category_id
WHERE
    asset_transaction.transaction_id = ($txnid)";
```

You would then call the function like this:

```
$query = $this->setGroupBy($strQuery, 'model');
```

or

```
$query = $this->setGroupBy($strQuery, 'type');
```

**EDIT**

So you would probably end up with this:

```
$baseQuery =
"SELECT
    category.short_description AS category,
    asset.asset_code AS code,
    asset_model_number.short_description AS model,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_1 AS mnfserial,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_6 AS proctype,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_7 AS hdd,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_8 AS type,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_9 AS cond,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_10 AS drive,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_12 AS os,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_13 AS cpu,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_14 AS ram,
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
    asset_transaction
LEFT JOIN asset 
  ON asset_transaction.asset_id = asset.asset_id
LEFT JOIN asset_model 
  ON asset.asset_model_id = asset_model.asset_model_id
LEFT JOIN asset_model_number 
  ON asset.asset_model_number_id = asset_model_number.asset_model_number_id
LEFT JOIN asset_custom_field_helper 
  ON asset.asset_id = asset_custom_field_helper.asset_id
LEFT JOIN user_account 
  ON asset.created_by = user_account.user_account_id
LEFT JOIN category 
  ON asset_model.category_id = category.category_id
WHERE asset_transaction.transaction_id = ($txnid)";

$objDatabase = QApplication::$Database[1];

// Create the query
$modelQuery = getQueryGroupBy($baseQuery, 'model'); 
// Perform the Query
$objDbResultByModel = $objDatabase->Query($modelQuery);
echo "<h3>Total Model No<br></h3><strong>";
while ($mixRow = $objDbResultByModel->FetchArray()) {
    echo $mixRow['model']. " = " .$mixRow['total'];
    echo "<br><strong>";
}

// Create the query
$typeQuery = getQueryGroupBy($baseQuery, 'type'); 
// Perform the Query
$objDbResultByType = $objDatabase->Query($typeQuery);
echo "<h3>Total Products<br></h3><strong>";
echo "<br>";
while ($row = $objDbResultByType->FetchArray()) {
    echo $row['type']. " = " .$row['total'];
    echo "<br><strong>";
}

function getQueryGroupBy($query, $type) {
    return $query . ' GROUP BY ' . $type;
}
```

Comment: Can you give me complete working example? I am bit lost. I am a newbie to PHP.

Comment: I have copied and pasted and it does not work. However, my original query works fine and produces results

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you :)

```
function getQuery( $order_by_string )
{ 
  return $query = 'Your query ....  ORDER BY '.$order_by_string
}

$query = getQuery("something");
```

Comment: yeah..this is more or less it. I would also show the user how to call the function within the code he has currently. If you can do that then you could save me a bit of time and earn yourself some extra rep. :)

Comment: That would be nice, if you can show me where to put this code and how to write by example. Thank you

Comment: you should probably include a return inside the function

Comment: I have tried this
<pre>
function   getQuery($order_by_string){ $strQuery =
        '                                SQL-Query

                                GROUP BY '.$order_by_string;

}
    $objDatabase = QApplication::$Database[1];

$query = getQuery("model");

echo "<h3>Total Model No<br></h3><strong>";
while ($mixRow = $query()) {
echo $mixRow['model']. " = " .$mixRow['total'];
echo "<br><strong>";
} </pre>

It does not work for me